# html <a> link javascript function with parameter

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass one parameter (text variable) from a `<a>` tag. This is the code that I'm using:

```
<a onclick='javascript:Page_Change('Previous')' class='PageLink'>Previous</a>
```

Without the parameter 'Previous' is O.K and the function is working correctly. There is any possibility to pass the parameter value only using pure js?

Comment: You may use double quotes around "Previous". But inline event handlers are just baaad....

Comment: <a onclick="javascript:Page_Change('Previous')" class='PageLink'>Previous</a>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it inline you can do this:

```
<a onclick="javascript:Page_Change('Previous')" class='PageLink'>Previous</a>
```

But it's better to keep it seperate like this:

```
<a id="prev" class = "PageLink">Previous</a>
```

You may bind the event handler using the jQuery library

```
<script>    
    // jQuery
    $('#prev').click(function() {
        Page_Change('Previous')
    });
</script>
```

or using standard JavaScript

```
<script>
    // javascript
    document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', function() { 
        Page_Change('Previous')
    }, false);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working but only one value (in this case 'previous') is possible to pass to the function.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest this, where you can pass a number of links having different parameters.

```
<a data-param="Previous" class="PageLink">Previous</a>
<a data-param="Next" class="PageLink">Next</a>
```

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("PageLink");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        Page_Change(e.target.getAttribute("data-param"))
    }, false);
}
```